# Send PDF as byte[] / JSON problem

Tags: json, pdf, servlets

I am trying to send a generated PDF file (Apache FOP) to the client. I know this can be done  by writing the array to the response stream and by setting the correct content type, length and so on in the servlet. My problem is that the whole app was built based on the idea that it will only receive/send JSON. In the servlet's service() method, I have this:

```
  response.setContentType("application/json");
  reqBroker.process(request, response);
```

RequestBroker is the class who processes the JSON (jackson processor), everything is generic and I cannot change  it. On top of this, I have to receive the JSON from the request correctly, to access the data and generate my pdf. So those two lines are necessary. But when I send the response, I need to have another content type so that the pdf is displayed correctly in the browser.
   So far, I am able to send the byte array as part of the JSON, but then I don't know how to display the array as PDF on the client (if smth like this is even possible). 
   I would like some suggestions on how can I send my pdf and set the right header, without messing with the JSON. Thanks.

Comment: What is the Client that you are sending to? If it's a web browser, why not set the content type to "application/pdf" and let the browser handle the displaying/downloading as the user has configured it.

Comment: When you say "the client" - do you just mean the browser? Or is there real client-side processing going on?

Comment: There is some client side processing of the response JSON..mainly javascript. I can't set the content type to "application/pdf" because it's already set to "application/json". This has to stay for the request, but for the response I need "application/pdf"

Comment: And with "application/pdf" the RequestBroker gets messed up.

Answer (score 1):

JSON and byte arrays don't mix.

Instead, you should create an `<iframe>` and point it to a URL that returns a raw PDF.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look here:[How to send pdf in json](http://www.thinkingcode.info/2015/05/how-to-send-pdf-in-json/), it lists couple of approaches that you can consider. The easiest way is to convert the binary data into string by using Base64 compression. In C#, this would mean a call to Convert.FromBase64String. However this has space overhead as Base64 compression means around +33% more memory. If you can get away with it, this is the least complicated solution. in case additional size is an issue you can think about zipping it up.

Comment: Whatever that site is, it requires a username and password.